# how to print the email in android

Tags: java, android

I am not able to send the email through editText .If I typed the email abc@gmail.com then I am able to print the email like abc. How I can read the full email abc@gmail.com.I am using this library https://github.com/splitwise/TokenAutoComplete/ and I am using following code in activity.How I can print the entered editText email in log.And How I can get this email in webservice.

```
public class Share_Activity extends Activity implements TokenCompleteTextView.TokenListener{

    ContactsCompletionView completionView;
    Person[] people;
    ArrayAdapter<Person> adapter;

    Button btnCancel,btnShare;
    EditText email_Text,email_Message;
    TextView share_text ;

    String alternate_id;
    String bookmark_title;
    String bookmark_url;
    String meassage;
    String email;
    String allemails;
    List<String> emails = new ArrayList<String>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_share);

        btnCancel =(Button) findViewById(R.id.share_cancel);
        btnShare =(Button) findViewById(R.id.share_button);
        share_text =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.share_text);
       // email_Text =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.share_email_text);
        email_Message =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.message_text);


        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

            if (extras == null) {

                alternate_id = null;
                bookmark_title = null;
                bookmark_url = null;


            } else {
                alternate_id = extras.getString("alternate_id");
                bookmark_title = extras.getString("bookmark_title");
                bookmark_url = extras.getString("bookmark_url");


            }
        } else {
            alternate_id = (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("alternate_id");
            bookmark_title = (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("bookmark_title");
            bookmark_url = (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("bookmark_url");

        }

          System.out.println(alternate_id);
          System.out.println(bookmark_title);
          System.out.println(bookmark_url);
          System.out.println("Value recevied");


        people = new Person[]{};



      /*  people = new Person[emails.size()];
        for(int i=0;i<emails.size();i++)
        {

            people[i]=new Person("",emails.get(i));
        }
        allemails= TextUtils.join(",", emails);
        Log.i("Result", allemails);*/
        adapter = new FilteredArrayAdapter<Person>(this, R.layout.person_layout, people) {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                if (convertView == null) {

                    LayoutInflater l = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    convertView = l.inflate(R.layout.person_layout, parent, false);
                }

                Person p = getItem(position);
                ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name)).setText(p.getName());
                ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.email)).setText(p.getEmail());

                return convertView;
            }

            @Override
            protected boolean keepObject(Person person, String mask) {
                mask = mask.toLowerCase();
                return person.getName().toLowerCase().startsWith(mask) || person.getEmail().toLowerCase().startsWith(mask);
            }
        };



        completionView = (ContactsCompletionView)findViewById(R.id.share_email_text);

        System.out.println(completionView);

        System.out.println("sngfh");
        completionView.setAdapter(adapter);
        completionView.setTokenClickStyle(TokenCompleteTextView.TokenClickStyle.Select);
        completionView.setTokenListener(this);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
           // completionView.setPrefix("To: ");
           // completionView.addObject(people[0]);
           // completionView.addObject(people[1]);
        }
        btnShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Dashboard.class);
                people = new Person[emails.size()];
                for(int i=0;i<emails.size();i++)
                {
                    people[i]=new Person("",emails.get(i));
                    System.out.println(emails.get(i));
                    System.out.println("hiiiiiii");
                }

                allemails = TextUtils.join(",", emails);
                System.out.println(allemails);
                System.out.println("allmailsca");
                meassage  = email_Message.getText().toString();
                allemails = completionView.getText().toString();

                System.out.println(meassage);
                System.out.println(allemails);

                new Share_LoaderTask().execute("https://www.myssite.com/users/sharearticle?", "access_token", alternate_id, bookmark_title, bookmark_url, meassage, allemails);
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });

    }
    class Share_LoaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
    {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
            // HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://www.mysites.com/secure-mobile/note?");

            String jsonResult = "";
            try {

                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(6);

                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("access_token", "94529e5dbc6234fc3bbfce7406b8dde9"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("alternateId",alternate_id));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("bookmarkTitle",bookmark_title));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("bookmarkUrl",bookmark_url));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("emails",allemails));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message",meassage));

                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                System.out.println(convertStreamToString(httpPost.getEntity().getContent()));
                System.out.println("Hiiiiiii");
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                int status = 200;

                if (status == 200) {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                    System.out.println(data);
                    System.out.println("fffff");
                    JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsono.length(); i++)
                    {

                    }
                    return null;
                }

                //------------------>>

            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
    private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            is.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
    private void updateTokenConfirmation() {

        emails = new ArrayList<String>();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Current tokens:\n");
        for (Object token: completionView.getObjects())
        {

            System.out.println(completionView.getObjects());
            System.out.println("hiiii");
            sb.append(token.toString());
            emails.add(token.toString());
            System.out.println(String.valueOf(emails.size()));
            System.out.println("hiiiiisfsfs");
            //System.out.println(emails.add(token.toString()));
            sb.append("\n");
        }
        System.out.println(sb);
        //((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tokens)).setText(sb);
    }
    @Override
    public void onTokenAdded(Object token) {

        updateTokenConfirmation();

    }

    @Override
    public void onTokenRemoved(Object token) {
        updateTokenConfirmation();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In xml file add the properties for edittext widget like this android:inputType="email"